# Embedded Jetty app with 2 ContextHandlers listening at same port - Loading issue

Tags: jetty, threadpool

My embedded jetty app (using 6.1.26 jetty) has 2 context handlers registered to it. Both are listening at same port. Below is the sample.

```
Server s = new Server();
Connector c = new SelectChannelConnector();
((SelectChannelConnector)connector).setAcceptors(2);
connector.setHost(IP);
connector.setPort(port);
server.addConnector(connector);

ContextHandler context1 = new ContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/abc");
context.setHandler(handler1);
context.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);

ContextHandler context2 = new ContextHandler();
context2.setContextPath("/xyz");
context2.setHandler(handler2);
context2.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);

ContextHandlerCollection hc = new ContextHandlerCollection();
hc.addHandler(context1);
hc.addHandler(context2);

server.setHandler(hc);
server.start();
```

I am also using a thread pool which is set at server level.
When I send requests to one context and put load on that so that all threads are used, At that time when I send a request to the second context its taking time to process the request to 2nd context.

I also tried by setting thread pool at SelectChannelConnector level and tried. 
Also tried by adding more connectors using same host/port so that each will have its own thread pool.

My requirement is that other context (but port is same) should not delay processing when one context is under load.

Can I have dedicated thread pool for each context. Is there any other work around.
Appreciate reply to this.

Thanks
Sarath

Answer (score 0):

With Jetty, the ThreadPool is at the connector level you can't have 2 different ThreadPools for handling different contexts.  As the connector accepts the request, it pulls a Thread from the ThreadPool, and hands it off to the Server.getHandler() chain. at which point it goes through the hierarchy of handlers until one of your Contexts is used.

This means that the knowledge of the context comes in far too late to split up the ThreadPools.

Have you tried upgrading to Jetty 8 or Jetty 9 and using [Async processing](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations#Why_Asynchronous_Servlets_.3F) instead?

Or have you tried using the [QoSFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/QoSFilter.html) in Jetty 7, 8, or 9 to prioritize the handling better?

Comment: I am using the Continuation feature present in 6.1.x so that the threads are not blocked when business logic gets executed. I did not try with newer versions. I need to check in v8 and see the behavior. Has anybody used custom thread pool or changed the thread count dynamically.